# Does the Linux kernel ever free memory allocated for the user mode stack?

Tags: linux, stack, kernel

I'm preparing for the OS exam and just realized that I don't know whether the kernel will ever unmap page table entries allocated for user mode stacks?

I have not been able to find an answer anywhere and it takes ages to read the kernel code, so I figured it might be faster to ask in here.

**Edit: I guess it's impossible for the kernel to know when to shrink the size of the stack. A system call to do so explicitly wouldn't hurt though.**

Answer (score 0):

The user thread is created by glic pthread library, and the user thread's stack is created by calling malloc().

The Linux's default user stack size is limited to 8MB by default. You can change by ulimit command:

```
       $ ulimit -s
       8192            # The stack size limit is 8 MB (0x800000 bytes)
```